# Button on click doesn't working -> transform

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my (burger) button.

When I click It's adding a class to my header-links, but class is not working -> I need to change on click from transform: translateX(100%) to transform: translateX(0);

I don't know why it's not working. Please help me, I tried a lot of ways to fix it but still, it's not working.

> My code so far:

```html
<header>
    <div class="header-logo">
        <p>ecodex</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="header-links">
        <li><a href="#container-two">O NAS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OFERTA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">KONTAKT</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="menu">
        <div class="line-one"></div>
        <div class="line-two"></div>
        <div class="line-three"></div>
    </div>
</header>
```

```
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;

  p {
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .header-active {
   transform: translateX(0);
  }
  .header-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 30%;
    list-style-type: none;
    li {
      font-size: 14px;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
      @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
      width: 60%;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      height: 90vh;
      top: 8vh;
      background: black;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      color: white;
      width: 50%;
      transform: translateX(100%);
      transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;

      .header-active {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
    }

  }
  .menu {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      display: block;
    }
    div {
   width: 25px;
   height: 2px;
   background-color: black;
   margin: 5px;
    }
  }
}
```

```
const headerSlide = () => {
    const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    const headerLinks = document.querySelector('.header-links');
    menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
        headerLinks.classList.toggle('header-active');
    });
}

headerSlide();
```

In the developer tools when I click the button the class 'header-active' is adding and removing - it's good, but don't know why my transform: translate(0) is not working.

Comment: Is the screen width greater than 768px in the environment where you're testing this? Because as your media query is written, it looks like `transform: translateX(100%)` is only in effect at smaller screen sizes. `translateX(0)` would be, I think, default CSS behavior, so unless you're at a larger screen size, `.header-active` wouldn't change anything.

Comment: Button appears only when the screen's width is equal or smaller than 768px. So is <= 768px and transform not working but class is adding on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
.header-active {    
  transform: translateX(0) !important;
}
```

The problem is that .header-links has translateX(100%), so translateX is ignored. I would move *transform: translateX (100%)* to another class and remove it before adding .header-links.

CSS

```
.tX100 {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="header-links tX100">
```

JS

```
headerLinks.classList.toggle('tx100');
headerLinks.classList.toggle('header-active');
```

Comment: Appreciate that